# how to select only two options in extJs 4.1 combobox multiselect

Tags: extjs, combobox, multi-select

i have some code that describes by column

```
cols.offer.push({
    dataIndex: 'tags',
    header : 'Тэги',
    width:150,
    editor : {
        xtype : 'combo',
        store :    gridTagStore,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        //valueField: 'name',
        multiSelect:true,
        typeAhead: true,
        editable:false,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        selectOnTab: true,
        lazyRender: true,
        listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
        listeners: {
            focus: function(e) {
                this.setValue(this.rawValue.split(', '));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

so I want to select only two options in combobox.

and I want if I would select third - nothing will happen

---

thanks!
it works for me!

```
  cols.offer.push({
    dataIndex: 'show_at_index_as_tag_id',
    header : 'Показывать на главной под тегом',
    width:150,
    editor : {
        xtype : 'combo',
        store :    gridTagStore,
        queryMode: 'local',
        typeAhead: true,
        displayField: 'name',
        selectOnTab: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        lazyRender: true,
        valueField: 'id',
        multiSelect:true,
        listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
        listeners: {
                beforeselect : function(){
                    return (this.value.length == 1 && this.value[0] === "") || this.value.length == 0 ;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I decided to limit with only one option and to use multiselect because I have store with options that is being used in other places of application.

But I need to select empty value in this combo, so multiselection with one option select is the good solution

Answer (score 2):

Add `beforeselect` listener to ComboBox. In the function define how many items already selected in ComboBox, if its count > 2 `return false;` to `do nothing`.